# Problems working with a column of a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a CSV file using this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import os 


#Open document (.csv format)
path=os.getcwd()
database=pd.read_csv(path+"/mydocument.csv",delimiter=';',header=0)

#Date in the requiered format 
size=len(database.Date)
```

I get the next error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'`

As you can see in the image, the first column of **mydocument.csv** is called **Date**. This is weird because I used this same procedure to work with this document, and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Honestly I find the documentation about the `header` parameter a bit confusing.  I am not sure what `header=0` means exactly in this context.  I would start by using `database.info()` to see what names it has actually assigned to the columns, and `database.head()` to see if it has loaded the header row as data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delimeter=',' . It must be a comma.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't post comments yet, but think I can help).

The explanation for your problem is, simply, you don't have a column called Date. Has pandas interpretted Date as an index column?

IF your Date is spelled correctly (no trailing whitespace or something else that might confuse things), then try this:

```
pd.read_csv(path+"/mydocument.csv",delimiter=';',header=0, index_col=False)
```

or if that fails this:

```
pd.read_csv(path+"/mydocument.csv",delimiter=';',header=0, index_col=None)
```

In my experience, I've had pandas unexpectedly infer an index_col.

Comment: I tried the way @Unbridledscum suggested, and it worked. I change the delimiter for a ',' and it worked

Comment: I assumed the semicolon was deliberate :) In some regions semicolon is the default delimiter when saving to csv with excel. In the future you can debug this yourself. Print the columns with

    print(database.columns)

or use another method like Dave Costa's suggestions.

Comment: The thing is that it worked well previously with the semicolon, so I did not expect this was the error. Thank you for your contribution. Could you vote up my question, please?